# How much do I need to invest monthly to accumulate a given amount?

Tags: investing, inflation

I have a target amount `T` USD (in today's value, before inflation) that I would like to accumulate over `N` years. Every month I invest `X` USD with an expected return of `Y%`. Expected inflation is `Z%` per year. How can I calculate whether I am investing enough? If that time is not enough, how long do I need to invest the money? How much should I invest monthly to meet the required deadline?

Comment: Is T the number of dollars at the end of the period, in which case the inflation figure is irrelevant, or is it a target in today’s dollars, in which case your targeted final balance is T(1+Z)^N?

Comment: @Lawrence I don't know where it went (I could have sworn it was in the comments), but T was in today's dollars. I tried to edit that into the question and that got rejected for some reason...

Comment: Found it. OP had originally mentioned that yes, the final balance is T(1+Z)^N. Some overzealous mod must have deleted the original answer, or I'm going crazy ;)

Comment: `T` in today's dollars

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you save `x` every month, the future value (FV) is

[image: annuity]

where

```
n is the number of months
r is the monthly rate of return
```

So if `Y%` return is 10% nominal interest compounded monthly

```
r = 0.10/12
```

For example, over 3 months, saving $100 per month

```
n  = 3
x  = 100
FV = (x (1 + r) ((1 + r)^n - 1))/r = 305.03
```

Checking the balance at the end of each month long-hand

```
b1 = 100 (1 + 0.1/12)        = 100.83
b2 = (b1 + 100) (1 + 0.1/12) = 202.51
b3 = (b2 + 100) (1 + 0.1/12) = 305.03
```

The formula checks out.

So after 10 years, saving $100 per month

```
n  = 120
x  = 100
FV = (x (1 + r) ((1 + r)^n - 1))/r = 20655.20
```

Discounting for inflation at, say, 2% per annum

```
FV/(1 + 0.02)^10 = 16944.46
```

Your future saving of $20,655 would have the purchasing power of $16,944 today.

To work it backwards, if you want $100,000 in today's value in 10 years

```
FV = 100000 (1 + 0.02)^10 = 121899.44

r  = 0.10/12
n  = 120

x  = (FV r)/((1 + r) ((1 + r)^n - 1)) = 590.16
```

You would need to save $590.16 each month.

***Compensating for inflation***

Inflation can be compensated for by increasing the monthly payments at the same rate as inflation.  This makes the payments equal in 'value' terms.

Inflation is usually quoted as an [effective annual rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation), so with 2% (as before) the monthly rate is obtained like so

```
i = (1 + 0.02)^(1/12) - 1 = 0.00165158
```

and the 3 month long-hand calculation becomes

```
b1 = 100 (1 + 0.1/12)                  = 100.83
b2 = (b1 + 100 (1 + i)) (1 + 0.1/12)   = 202.67
b3 = (b2 + 100 (1 + i)^2) (1 + 0.1/12) = 305.53
```

This can be expressed as a formula

[image: with inflation]

[image: initial payment]

Once again, to save $100,000 in today's value over ten years

```
FV = 100000 (1 + 0.02)^10  = 121899.44
n  = 120
i  = (1 + 0.02)^(1/12) - 1 = 0.00165158
r  = 0.10/12

x  = (FV (i - r))/((1 + r) ((1 + i)^n - (1 + r)^n)) = 542.84
```

The first payment is $542.84, and the payments increase like so

```
month 1    x (1 + i)^0   = 542.84
month 2    x (1 + i)^1   = 543.74
month 3    x (1 + i)^2   = 544.63
...
month 120  x (1 + i)^119 = 660.63
```

Comment: Note that these formulas assume deterministic returns.  If returns are uncertain, you can use simulation to estimate your probability of having enough by a date in the future.

Comment: How does this change if you consider inflation in the amount saved?

Comment: I have added a calculation to raise the payment amounts in line with inflation.

Comment: Awesome! Now I just have to figure out what each term actually means. Should probably go back to high school... :p